# How to install pstocanonij filter in cups for canon printer (12.04 64 bit)?

Tags: printing, canon

I've been trying to install my Canon mp620 printer to my new laptop for a couple of days now without joy.

I've tried every instruction I can find online and only one has come close to working: it finds the wireless printer and installs the driver (Canon MP620-630 BKIntegration Ver.4.0 Universal), but I get a message in the printer status box that says:

> Idle - File "`/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocanonij`" not available: No such file or directory

I've looked in the folder and that file is missing. I've found the file on my old laptop (running 12.04 32bit and the same printer) but because its a root permission only folder, I can't add it to the new one.

I don't know if adding it will solve the problem but can someone tell me how to do it?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried setting the printer up in cups now that you've installed the driver?

Comment: `sudo -i` should give you access to any folder. however moving a system file from a 32 bit system to a 64 bit system might have unintended consequences. I would be hesitant to do so without a full backup in hand.

Comment: @Elder Geek: "setting the printer up in cups" is not a helpful answer to someone unfamiliar with cups. Or even where cups is. Or how to get it. Or how to install it or invoke it. Or find it if it is installed. It's just plain unhelpful.

Comment: @Steve cups is the "Common Unix Printing System" I highly doubt that an answer based around adding a filter to cups in v.12.04 of Ubuntu would be useful to you today regardless. If you are still using 12.04 I highly recommend that you upgrade to a supported version. If not, You might wish to ask a new question based on the supported version of Ubuntu you are currently running. You can obtain that information by running `lsb_release -a` at the CLI. (terminal)

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

**Step 1**

Open your Terminal and Install a `printer-driver-gutenprint` package:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

---

**Step 2**

Remove your current printer from ***Settings > Printers***.

> Only if you have added it before. If not, skip this step.

---

**Step 3**

Add a new Printer (*open **Settings > Printers***), and choose which printer you want to use. and then, Ubuntu system will automatically configure the Printer with the `printer-driver-gutenprint` that has been installed in **Step 1**.

---

**Step 4**

Finish. Now you can print normally as usual.

---

**Tested On**

- Ubuntu 20.04